# Why push async not returns immediately in Xamarin Forms

Tags: navigation, xamarin.forms

I thought PushAsync should return Task immediately after call(I want to make several actions while new layout is appearing). But for this code

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
Task task = Navigation.PushAsync(newRoot);
Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms"); // 1000 ms
await task;
Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");// 1500 ms
stopwatch.Stop();
```

first writeline show about 1 second, second writeline called in 0.5 sec after first. How to improve PushAsync so it will return immediately?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PushAsync is an asynchronous method which means it does the task in the background so not to hold up the application and block any of the other resources.

If you require an immediate response you need to use a synchronous method instead of asynchronous.

Comment: First, there is no any synchronous method for push. Second, synchronous method in any case will not return immediately, instead of this it return when all work will be done(for this example, after 1.5 sec)

Comment: I agree, with what you are saying, but as the task is aSynchronous, it will always run in the background which is a lower priority than any of the foreground tasks.

Comment: I suppose you to speed up the response, you would need to reduce the foreground activities enabling the background activity to run more quickly?

Comment: Maybe, my queestion was not clear. 1,5 sec for rendering page is normal for me. But why background operation(PushAsync) works in main thread for 1 sec?

Answer (score 0):

I have several applications using NavigationPage and have never seen it take a second to request navigation. You don't happen to have have hooked the PushRequested or Pushed events, have you? Those are invoked synchronously and could easily inject a delay if you have complex code in your handlers.

Comment: No, I don't hook this events. As I see, e.g base implementation of OnSizeAllocated delay for 450 ms. So if I have a complex page, xamarin forms build layout in main thread